# Ajax success don't execute

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring

I'm doing a login page with Spring MVC in server and JS & Ajax in client. I don't know what's wrong, the code of the server executes but don't return nothing.
login.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".loguser").click(function() {
            var user = $("#login").val();
            var pass = $("#pass").val();            
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url : "${prefix}loginUser",
                data : "username=" + user + "&password=" + pass,
                dataType : "json",
                success: function(data){
                    if (data.res == "YES") alert("ok");
                    else alert("NOPE");
                }

            });
        })
    })
</script>
    <table id="userData" class="center">

                    <tr id="usernametr">
                        <th><label for="user">Nombre de usuario: </label></th>
                        <th><input id="login" type="text" name="login" value=""
                            placeholder="Name" required /></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><br /></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><label for="pass">Clave de usuario: </label></th>
                        <th><input id="pass" type="password" name="pass" value=""
                            placeholder="Password" required /></th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>                        
                        <th><button class="loguser">Acceder</button></th>
                        <th><input type="button" name="lost"
                            value="He perdido mi clave" /></th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

HomeController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginUser")
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public String loginUser(@RequestParam("username") String username,
            @RequestParam("password") String pass, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        logger.info("Trying to log in {} {}", username, pass);
        if (username.length() > 3) {
            logger.info("ok");
            return new String("[\"res\": \"YES\"]");
        } else {
            logger.warn("nope");
            return new String("[\"res\": \"NOPE\"]");
        }
    }
```

I tryiend returning EntityResponse too but nothing change. Springs console prints the logger info or warn but Firefox's javascript console doesnt.

Comment: How does it came that your handler method get called while it is bound to GET request while your are firing a POST one from client side! Could you please provide the whole `HomeController` body?

Comment: You are aware you are returning `NOPE` in both cases?

Comment: There is nothing more in the HomeController. Its marked as <code>@Controller</code>.
@RealSkeptic LOL yeah, I changed it in the post but in my source is diferent, I change it now here.

Comment: Have you tried to access the URL directly to see what it returns if anything?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Nop, how can I do it? You mean reinvasion/loginUser?login=asdf&pass=asdasd ? If its yes, yes, I tryied and I recive Error 405 Request method 'Get' not supported.

Comment: You can do it in POST by creating a simple HTML file with a form that has two fields, METHOD=POST and an ACTION that is your URL, and submitting that form in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify Requestmethod in controller like

> @RequestMapping(value = "/loginUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)

You must Return Json Values In  { } 
Braces

Comment: Nop, It didn't change anything. It doesn't execute success function :( I have tryied it before.

Comment: The logger prints, everything in the controller runs well, the problem is that It doesn't return the execution to the success function. An example from the logger:
INFO : es.ucm.reinvasion.HomeController - Trying to log in sdsadw rrasa
INFO : es.ucm.reinvasion.HomeController - ok
INFO : es.ucm.reinvasion.HomeController - Trying to log in das asdasa
WARN : es.ucm.reinvasion.HomeController - nope

Comment: Try this -- >   $.ajax({  url : '/loginUser',   data : {  username : username,                      password : password, }, type : 'POST', success : function(data) { } });  and change you "var user " name as "var username" and same as "Password"

Comment: Remove new String and Just  'return "[\"res\": \"NOPE\"]" '

Comment: does the logger prints "ok"?

Comment: Yes. Then it refresh the page with the values in direction box like /login?login=asdf&pass=asdasd and no one alert dialog shows.

Comment: you must use {} these braces in returning json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73485/discussion-between-aravinthan-k-and-furia1521).

Comment: Yeah... I noticed it and changed but it stills wrong.


OK, I don't know what but I changed executed it with Chromium and works. Thanks.

Comment: check data with console.. what it prints?